# Time Varying Coefficient Model with Uniform Kernel and Spline Estimator

Tags: r, nonparametric, kernel-smoothing, splines

I'm working on the BMACS data set data(BMACS) from library(npmlda).

I'm looking at the the time-varying coefficient model of post-CD4 versus smoking $X_1$, pre-HIV CD4 percent $X_2$ (centered) and age $X_3$ (centered), i.e. $Y(t) = \beta(t) + \beta_1(t)X_1 + \beta_2(t)X_2 + \beta_3(t)X_3 +\epsilon(t)$.  I am trying to give the estimates of the coefficient curves at different time points and come up with a plot, using the following smoothing methods,

1. kernel estimator using the $Uniform(−1/2, 1/2)$ kernel and bandwidth h = 0.5
2. spline estimator using the cubic spline with two interior knots $ξ_1$ = 2 and $ξ_2$ = 4.

```
#Centered pre-HIV CD4 percent and also centered the age as required
BMACS$preCD4C <- BMACS$preCD4 - mean(BMACS$preCD4)
BMACS$ageC <- BMACS$age - mean(BMACS$age)
```

I found a package tvReg to do the analysis,

```
tvLM(CD4 ~ Smoke  + preCD4C + ageC, data = BMACS)
```

however, tvReg only uses Triweight (default), Epa or Gaussian kernel functions, which is not what I'm looking for.

I am not sure how to proceed going forward. I would appreciate any tips and guidance!